# Looking for formula to lookup name when multiple criteria is matched including comma separated values

Tags: google-sheets-formula

There are two tabs in the sheet, Form Responses and Count Overview. I am trying to lookup the MA Name and email address in the count overview tab based on matching the branch name and department counted from the form response sheet based on Column C =Assigning a Managing Auditor, lookup the department counted in cell B2 in teh Count Overview tab and the Branch, then return Column F+G in the response sheet based on the matching credentials.

In the form response sheet column E (Please select the department(s) you are MA for could have comma separated values which I want to use to match which Department Counted is in cell B2 in the Count overview tab to return the MA Name and MA Email address when they match.

So in summary the Form Responses will have either Assigning a Managing Auditor or Managing Auditor ICE Sign Off in Column C. For Assigning a Managing Auditor which will include which departments they are MA for (Column E) and their MA Name and Email Address in Column F+G.

In the Count overview tab it is filtering based on Managing Auditor ICE Sign Off and I want it to return the MA Name and MA Email Address

I've shared the sheet if it makes more sense.

[Copy of Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1USDwi2sFkVlVs5MbO8TYTvazlazQm0S2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106030403607053457352&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: for Small Electrical the MA Name and MA Email Address are empty. pls add more details to your question

Comment: Sorry I don't think I've explained it well enough.